# Return YES or NOT if text from a list is in this cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Pretty straightforward but couldnt do it.

I have a list of words on A:A.

I am trying to make a function that will tell you whether or not the word you write in a specific cell is on that list.

So you have the cell B5, and you type "PURPLE". If the word "PURPLE" is on the list (A:A) it will return "Yes" on B6, otherwise it will return "No".

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B5; A:A; 0); FALSE)=TRUE; "yes"; "no")
```

Comment: I changed it to =IF(MATCH(B5, A:A,0)=TRUE, "NO", "YES") because it was giving me an error. Now it works, but if the word is not there it returns #N/A instead of "NO". How can I solve that?

Comment: @coffee709 answer updated

Answer (score 0):

1. First, use the MATCH Function to lookup the word in the list. If it finds a match, it will return the relative position, which is a number. If it fails to find a match, it will return an error.
2. Next, we'll use the ISNUMBER Function to check for a number. It returns TRUE for a number and FALSE if not.
3. Finally, we use the IF Function to check if the result of the ISNUMBER is TRUE, which means there's a match. We return "Yes" for TRUE and "No" for FALSE.

Here's the final formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B5,A:A,0)),"Yes","No")
```